# Phonegap Android ajax call failed in compiled app but ok in emulator

Tags: ajax, cordova, phonegap-build

I am maintaining a Android app which I compile with Adobe PhoneGap Build. It worked very well since the beginning of its development. Nevertheless, today the login function (done through an ajax call) does not work anymore although it has not been modified for long time. After analysis, it appears that the ajax call receives this response:

> { readyState: 4, responseText: '', status: 404, statusText: Not Found }

However, I do not meet that problem when I use the app with the PhoneGap Emulator on my phone.. And the app compiled 9 days ago is still working very well, but not if I recompile from that code!

Do you know where the problem could come from ?

Thanks!

Pierre

Comment: 404 comes only when there is problem in specifying sever address and webservice name/parameter formats in ajax call ..so will recommend you to check ajax server URL first in your latest code

Comment: Hello, thanks for your comment. That's what I though. Nevertheless, it works perfectly in the emulator and as I just added in my question, if I recompile the code of the previous build with Phonegap Build, it also does not work anymore. Maybe something has been change in the PhoneGap Build compiler?

Comment: Sorry..no idea..thanx for your petience

Comment: @Pierre, Please read the response on this thread. You have a similar, if not the same problem. [Phonegap ... stopped working in phonegap build](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32775980/phonegap-cross-domain-json-data-calling-stopped-working-in-phonegap-build)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, it works now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem with my app.
After reading #10 in this link:
https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md
try adding this line to your config file:

```
<gap:plugin name="com.indigoway.cordova.whitelist.whitelistplugin" version="1.1.1" />
```

after adding this line my app works great. hope it helps you too..

Comment: Exactly, that line is necessary. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't u check code for ajax call within apk. U can extract code from apk too. I also have the same issue. Even after changing ip address for server in code, it wasn't updating in apk on creating build. To solve this I removed android platform from phonegap project and added it back.

Comment: Have you added <access> policy for your server in phonegap config.XML ?

Comment: Yes, I set up this long time ago actually. But something I noticed is that the phonegap ajax calls referred to https://myserver.com while the access policy referred to https://www.myserver.com. I had also to remove the 'www.' in the access origin setting to make it working (however before it was not a problem).