# Phonegap errors everywhere

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I'm trying to get started by building a sample mobile app with phonegap

I've installed everything needed.

when I run `phonegap create` it creates a lot of files that I haven't seen in any tutorials yet.

I'm using Version 5.3.5

I've installed it using `sudo npm install -g phonegap`

**What I've done**

I have uploaded the sample app to github and build from the .git link.

when I downloaded the .apk to my android using the qr code scanner it installed normally and I was able to connect `Device is Ready` appeared.

But when I try to debug there are no targets.

When I enabled Hydration and re-build, the app updates but it no longer connects to device.`Connecting to Device` appears and doesn't leave the screen.

The only changes I've done is to the `config.xml` file to add the source for the plugins

```
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.battery-status" source="npm"/>
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.camera" source="npm"/>
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media-capture" source="npm"/>
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.console" source="npm"/>
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.contacts" source="npm"/>
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" source="npm"/>
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-motion" source="npm"/>
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-orientation" source="npm"/>
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.dialogs" source="npm"/>
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file" source="npm"/>
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file-transfer" source="npm"/>
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.geolocation" source="npm"/>
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.globalization" source="npm"/>
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" source="npm"/>
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media" source="npm"/>
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.network-information" source="npm"/>
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen" source="npm"/>
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.vibration" source="npm"/>
```

I added `source="npm"` in order to fix errors.

This is the `index.html` file that it creates:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
    Copyright (c) 2012-2014 Adobe Systems Incorporated. All rights reserved.

    Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
    or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
    distributed with this work for additional information
    regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
    to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
    "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
    with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

    Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
    software distributed under the License is distributed on an
    "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
     KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
    specific language governing permissions and limitations
    under the License.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
        <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="app">
            <h1>PhoneGap</h1>
            <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
                <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
                <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            app.initialize();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

But I'm pretty confuse as to why a `cordova.js` file is imported instead of the `phonegap.js` file that I've seen in every tutorial.

Also, it creates a bunch of folders:

```
--hooks
--platforms
--plugins
--www
config.xml
```

I'm connected in the same wifi with the laptop and android device.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please read response: [Phonegap...stopped working in phonegap build](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32775980/phonegap-cross-domain-json-data-calling-stopped-working-in-phonegap-build)

Comment: Are you able to browse to the App from the same IP address in your browser ?